# Jenkins: Aborting a build with a catchError()

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

In my Jenkins scripted pipeline, I am executing 1 stage with some tasks and then sending Slack messages. I want to send these Slack messages if the previous stage passes or fails and to do this I am using a `catchError()` and it works exactly as I need to. My problem arises when I want to abort the build.

If I abort the build, I want to exit the build entirely and not send the Slack messages, but my `catchError()` is catching this abort and then continuing the pipeline and sending the messages.

```
stage('first stage with catchError') {
    catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE', catchInterruptions: false) {
        // Do some stuff here and continue the build if anything fails
    }
}

stage('second stage that send slack messages) {
    // Send some Slack messages based on the data produced in the first stage and based on if the tasks were a success or they failed
}
```

I thought I could use the `catchInterruptions` option in the `catchError()` to abort the entire build (here is a link for the [docs for this function](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure)), but that clearly hasn't resulted in the behaviour I want. What shall I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just being stupid and misunderstanding the documentation. I just needed to set the `catchInterruptions` option to true (which is the default value).

```
    catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE', catchInterruptions: true) {
        // Do some stuff here and continue the build if anything fails
    }
```

OR (because true is the default value)

```
    catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
        // Do some stuff here and continue the build if anything fails
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by setting `catchInterruptions` to `false`:

```
catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE', catchInterruptions: false) {
    // Do some stuff here and continue the build if anything fails
}
```

Now, all stages are aborted with one click when we abort a build. Where previously, we would have to abort each stage individually.